# How to create Array with range in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, it is possible to create an array with elements (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html):

```
SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3,4] AS indexes;
```

Is there a function to generate an array by specifying begin and end? like

```
SELECT array_from_to(1, 4) AS indexes
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use a combination of the `ARRAY` function with `generate_series`, e.g.

```
SELECT ARRAY(
    SELECT a.n
    FROM generate_series(1, 4) AS a(n)
);
```

### Demo

Comment: [Could be](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=889997316f990a993a7fa3b07a77e806) even shorter: `ARRAY(SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 4))`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `ARRAY_AGG` function in conjunction with the  `GENERATE_SERIES` function.

For example:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(index) AS indexes
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1,4) AS index;
```

Output:

```
  indexes  
-----------
 {1,2,3,4}
```